# Flask-SQLAlchemy missing "caching_sha2_password" authentication module

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to follow the Flask-SQLAlchemy quickstart guide (http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/).  When I perform any database operation such as `db.create_all()`, I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.\r\n")`

I understand that this is due to the default identification method having changed within MySQL8.  I opened a mysqlshell and ran these -

```
CREATE USER 'myapp'@'localhost' IDENTIFIES WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* 'myapp'@'localhost';
```

Which seemed to work alright.  However, even after updating the config details to use this new user with

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql:////myapp:password@localhost/mydatabase'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

the same error persists.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using the `pymysql` dialect in the URL:

`mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/database`

Answer (score 0):

This is not "the solution", but for the hapless googlers this is what I did -
I uninstalled python 3.7 and reverted to python 3.6, in order to use MySQL's official python connector.  I installed pymysql and changed the URI in my config to mysql+pymysql:// etc.  This seems to have left me with a functioning app.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql:////myapp:password@localhost/mydatabase?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password'
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.params.query